Dictionary with multiple values in Python
I am trying to improve a code that I've made. The idea is to automate some data processing.
The idea is to link two dictionaries so that I can "easily" move from key/values and format outputs.
I now have :
my_first_dict = {"value_1": "value_1_formatted", value_2: "value_2_formatted", ...}
my_second_dict = {"value_1_formatted": "value_1_formatted_differently", "value_2_formatted": "value_2_formatted_differently", ...")

Doing so allows me to identify and rename as I want using key/value pairs. However, it can sometimes make code heavier and less readable.
I'd like to know if there is a more efficient way to proceed. I was wondering if, for example, we could have a "three layer dictionary", with values/keys accessible via : .keys() or .values()[...].
That would look like :
my_dict = {"value_1": "value_1_formatted": "value_1_formatted_differently"}

Where my_dict["value_1"].values()[1] would return "value_1_formatted_differently" (it doesn't work, it's just to present my idea of it)
What do you think about ?

You can have a dict where the values are collections themselves, i.e. the value is a list of multiple values or another dict with another key-value. You can't have the kind of dict you show though.

You can have my_dict = {"value_1": ["value_1_formatted", "value_1_formatted_differently"]} and then my_dict["value_1"][1]. What problem do you want to solve or make easier with your approach?

Do you ever need to lookup "value_1_formatted_differently" from "value_1_formatted" directly, or are you usually/always doing so via starting with "value_1"?

@MichaelButscher doing so won't allow me to move from "value_1_formatted" to "value_1_formatted_differently" no ?
The idea is that I need to perform different checks across my code, and throughout it, variables won't have the same namings (i.e, I'm exporting data into excel, and the columns names would correspond to the "formatted_differently" section, while in my db it would correspond to only "_formatted", and my input file correspondent to value_1 and so on (@JonSG too)

Maybe a dictionary is the wrong datatype for your application. Did you consider using a dataclass for that? In the past this helped me to overcome problems I ran into with dictionaries. Using a dataclass instead of a dictionary also made it more readable for me.

That "three layer dictionary" syntax is obviously not valid, but you can achieve the same idea by just doing a nested lookup
>>> my_second_dict[my_first_dict["value_1"]]
'value_1_formatted_differently'

In other words, starting with your key first look up the value from the first dict, then use that as the key for the next lookup.

Indeed, it's not (it was more to share the idea than a line of code :D)
Looks good, thanks ! But anyway, I would need to create 2 dictionnaries to do so ?

If the keys don't collide, you can my_dict = my_first_dict.clone(); my_dict.update(my_second_dict) and then my_dict[my_dict["value_1"]]

If "value_1" is your common name, true key and "value_1_formatted" and "value_1_formatted_differently" are aliases that you would like to uncover based on the key/common name, then I would likely use something like this nested dictionary:
my_lookup = {
    "Jonny": {
        "formatted": "Jon",
        "formatted_differently": "Jonathan"
    },
    "Annie": {
        "formatted": "Anna",
        "formatted_differently": "Anastasia"
    },
}

Then you can:
key = "Annie"
print(my_lookup[key]["formatted_differently"])

This also might allow you to have incomplete data. For example:
my_lookup = {
    "Jonny": {
        "formatted": "Jon",
        "formatted_differently": "Jonathan"
    },
    "Annie": {
        "formatted": "Anna",
        ##"formatted_differently": "Anastasia"   <--- Now missing
    },
}

Then
key = "Annie"
print(my_lookup[key].get("formatted_differently", key))


This looks super cool for what I want to do, thanks a lot ;) I'm gonna try right now

I would suggest using 2D array, e.g. list of lists to store 2 different formats for each key, for example
columns = {"column1":0,"column2":1,"column3":2}  # associate names with 0-based column names
rows = {"firstformat":0,"secondformat":1}  # associate names with 0-based row names
array = [["value1format1","value2format1","value3format1"],["value1format2","value2format2","value3format2"]]  # each sublist is one row
print(array[rows["secondformat"]][columns["column3"]])  # output is value3format2

If you are allowed to use external packages you might pandas.DataFrame for that purpose following way
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([["value1format1","value2format1","value3format1"],["value1format2","value2format2","value3format2"]],columns=("column1","column2","column3"),index=("firstformat","secondformat"))
print(df["column3"]["secondformat"])

